# How to convert a simple summation into algebraic expression?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to simplify a calculation by making a summation an algebraic expression:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} a^i $$

I have no idea how to do this, since when I expand the sum's first few terms it's difficult to find aw simple expression for it, that doesn't expand with $n$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^n a^i=\dfrac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}\forall a(\neq 1)\in\Bbb R$

Answer (score 2):

This is the partial sum of the geometric sequence and we have (if $a\neq 1$)

$$\sum_{i=0}^n a^i=\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}.$$

**Edited**

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a^i=\frac{a-a^{n+1}}{1-a}.$$

and in general

$$\sum_{i=p}^n a^i=\frac{a^p-a^{n+1}}{1-a}.$$

Comment: The commenter has given a slightly different answer, which is correct?

Comment: I've edited my question slightly, I typoed something in the summation

Comment: It's the same answer: just multiply the numerator and denominator by $-1$.

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks. What about with the modified sum?

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there a name for this identity, or a derivation I can use, just so I understand how to get to this result?

Comment: As I wrote in my answer this is the partial sum of the geometric sequence and you can prove this result by many ways: change of index, induction and other.

Answer (score 0):

Define 
$$
S:=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a^i
$$
Then
$$
aS=\sum_{i=0}^{n}a^{i+1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a^i,
$$
and so
$$
(1-a)S=S-aS=a^0-a^{n+1}.
$$
Assuming $a\neq 1$, dividing both sides by $1-a$ yields
$$
S=\frac{1-a^{n+1}}{1-a}.
$$

(If $a=1$, then of course $a^i=1$ for all $i$, so that $S=n+1$.)

**Edit:** The OP has changed the index of summation to start at 1.  This can be accounted for by noticing that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^i=a\sum_{i=1}^{n}a^{i-1}=a\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a^i=a\frac{1-a^n}{1-a}=\frac{a-a^{n+1}}{1-a}.
$$